# $(X,Z) \stackrel{D}{=} (Y,Z)$ implies $\mathbb{E}[f(X) \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[f(Y) \mid Z]$ for any $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory

A more precise formulation of the problem is as follows:

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables such that $(X,Z)$ and $(Y,Z)$ have the same joint distribution; that is, $\mathbb{P}[X \in B,Z \in B'] = \mathbb{P}[Y \in B,Z \in B']$ for all $B,B' \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Borel algebra. Show that $\mathbb{E}[f(X) \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[f(Y) \mid Z]$ almost surely, where $f$ is any real-valued function.

By linearity of expectation, this problem is equivalent to showing that $0 = \mathbb{E}[f(X) - f(Y) \mid Z]$. It is obvious that $0$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable, so it remains to show that $\mathbb{E}[(f(X) - f(Y))1_A] = 0$ for all $A \in \sigma(Z)$.

This is where I'm stuck. I feel that the trick is similar to showing the [uniqueness (up to a.s.) of conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280701/proof-of-uniqueness-of-conditional-expectation), where we cleverly choose $A_{\epsilon} = \{f(X) - f(Y) > \epsilon\}$, and show that it occurs with probability $0$. However, I'm not sure how to guarantee that $A_\epsilon$ lies in $\sigma(Z)$, hence I can't proceed.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A\in\sigma(Z)$ there is a $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A=\{Z\in B\}$. Now,
$$
\int_\Omega f(X)\mathbf{1}_A\mathrm dP=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\mathbf{1}_B(z)P_{(X,Z)}(\mathrm dx,\mathrm dz)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(y)\mathbf{1}_B(z)P_{(Y,Z)}(\mathrm dy,\mathrm dz)=\int_\Omega f(Y)\mathbf{1}_A\mathrm dP
$$
showing that $\mathrm{E}[(f(X)-f(Y))\mathbf{1}_A]=0$ as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have (and the course I'm taking does not require) background on Lebesgue integral. Is there a way to solve this without using Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @ClementYung If you don't know about Lebesgue integrals, then how do you define expectations and conditional expectations?

Comment: We follow the definitions in Ross' 2nd Course in Probability, which says:
$$
\mathrm{E}[X] \equiv \sup_{\text{all simple variables }Y \leq X}\mathrm{E}[Y]
$$
and, the conditional expectaion $\mathrm{E}[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$ to be the random variables $Z$ such that 1) $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and 2) $\mathrm{E}[Z1_A] = \mathrm{E}[X1_A]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @ClementYung Well, that is actually how the Lebesgue integral is defined. I'm not sure there is a shorter path for showing the result than to rely on the "change-of-variables"-formula for the Lebesgue integral which is what I did in my post. The formula is what is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) or alternatively [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236077/how-expected-value-is-related-to-density-function/237022#comment524888_237022).